# Combining two queries using JOIN, GROUP BY and SUM?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am stuck trying to write the correct query for this problem. So I have 2 tables `orders` and `products` where `orders.user_id=products.buyer_id`

I want to query from both tables and find out how much each person `owes` for their purchase, how much they actually `paid`, and finally the `difference` between the two (`owes-paid`).

[image]

The individual queries that work are

```
SELECT buyer_id, SUM(price) AS owes FROM products GROUP BY buyer_id ORDER BY buyer_id ASC;
```

and

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount_paid) AS paid FROM orders GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id ASC;
```

I am able to do the right query but only on each table individually. However, when trying to combine both queries (Outer Join?), I get bad results.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a sub query where you take the union of both, and dedicate a column to the paid amount and another to the due amount. Then apply the aggregation on that sub query:

```
SELECT user_id,
       SUM(amount_due) AS owes,
       SUM(amount_paid) AS paid,
       SUM(amount_due) - SUM(amount_paid) AS diff
FROM (
        SELECT user_id, amount_paid, 0 amount_due
        FROM   orders 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT buyer_id, 0, price
        FROM   products
     ) AS transactions
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id ASC;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I was using JOIN and was getting all types of wrong answers. I have to do some more practice with UNION. Really appreciate it.